# How to create a query in MySql so that the values checked step by step. Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have

```
$words = Word::where('module_id', '=', [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])
            ->offset(290)->take(30)->get();
```

The result is only 10 words of the first module. And from the second does not take values.
Already tortured with these requests, can someone tell me how to do this?

Comment: do you want to return all the words if module_id is either any one from the ``[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]``? If so, you can use ``Word::whereIn('module_id', [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])->offset(290)->take(30)->get();``

Comment: @OMiShah whereIn checks all words in which the given module is present. My words in the database are out of order. I need to sort them in such a way that the words from module 1 are taken first, then from module 2, and so on. I could sort by modules, but I'm not sure if it's not too resource intensive.

Comment: then you can order/sort it using the orderBy() method on the builder as: ``Word::whereIn('module_id', [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])->orderBy('module_id', 'ASC')->offset(290)->take(30)->get();``

Comment: @OMiShah Please post answers in the answer space below, not as comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to return all the words if `module_id` is either any one from the `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]` then you can use the `whereIn()` method to build the query:

```
Word::whereIn('module_id', [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])->offset(290)->take(30)->get();
```

but since you want the result to be sorted/ordered by ascending module_id, use the `orderBy()` method on the eloquent query builder as:

```
Word::whereIn('module_id', [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])->orderBy('module_id', 'ASC')->offset(290)->take(30)->get();
```

*Posting as answer after suggested by @Dharman.*